# Divide Vector by matrix

Tags: r, matrix, division

I want to translate a `Matlab` code and I'm kind of stuck. I want to calculate `A/B` where `A` is a 1x3 vector and `B` a 3x3 matrix. In `Matlab` it works perfectly. The solution should be `C`.

I thought about changing the formula to

AB^(-1)

What have I forgotten? What is the equivalent to Matlab `A/B`?

```r
A <- structure(c(0.203087815504433, -0.185526315789458, 2.06128903508772), .Dim = c(1L, 3L))
B <- structure(c(0.162362619308917, 0.00102409360829869, 0.0271730132253801, 0, 0.010825744280011, 0.00830177798871224, 0, 0, 0.0526477214917381), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
C <- c(-11.794, 14.789, 34.757)

A %*% solve(B)
```

**EDIT:** I made a mistake when I wanted to simplify the example... I don't know what I did wrong, the matrices look the same to me? For the sake of completeness:

```r
Sigma <- matrix(c(0.40294, 0, 0, -0.032001, 0.10405, 0, 0.16484, -0.091114, 0.22945), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
epsilon_temp <- c(0.50401, -1.6281, 7.975)
covariance <- matrix(c(0.16236, -0.012895, 0.066422, -0.012895, 0.01185, -0.014755, 0.066422, -0.014755, 0.088123), nrow = 3)

t(Sigma %*% epsilon_temp) %*% solve(covariance) #right solution

a <- t(Sigma %*% epsilon_temp)
b <- covariance
a %*% solve(b) #right solution
```

Comment: The dollar signs were actually intended for math mode. They are not related to Matlab. So that nobody gets confused I took them out.

Comment: Hmm...usually we use `sweep` in R for such divisions, i.e. `sweep(B, 2, A, '/')` but it does not seem to be what you want

Comment: What I meant was how does matlab handle division of unequal dimensions of matrices. Can you explain calculation behind first value of -11.794 ? How did you get that?

Comment: It would be great if you had an example with rounder numbers. As Sotos said, the usual solution is to `sweep` an operation across the rows or columns of your matrix but that’s clearly not what you’re after — but it’s not clear *what* you’re after. Further, executing `A / B` in Matlab for your data does not even remotely yield `C`.